# how to download ipad sdk

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

I would like to download ipad sdk (i.e.iphone sdk 3.2),but i think it requires a mac osX Snow Leopard version  10.6.2 or later.But i have only Mac Osx Version 10.5.8 (build:9L31A).So,i made a software update but i couldnot find mac osx update in the software update list.I would like to know how to update my mac to 10.6.2 and install iphone sdk 3.2 for developing ipad Applications.

Thank You In Advance..

Comment: This is a question about OS versions, not programming, and it belongs on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

To move from 10.5.x to 10.6.x you have to buy Snow Leopard.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC223?mco=MTAyNTQ0NDI

Answer (score 0):

You are right about having to upgrade to Snow. I'm now on Snow and I have iPad SDK installed (iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 3). Please note that you also need to be registered to the iPhone Developer Program to be able to download the 3.2 beta.

Amazon used to sell it for a lower price, 24 USD I think, but it's now also at [29 USD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AMHWP8).

Comment: I am registered with iPhone Developer Program ,i don't have mac 10.6.2 to download..is there no other way than puchasing it?

Comment: As far as I know, that's the only legal route to upgrading to Snow Leopard. 

If you want to save a bit on costs you can also purchase the Family pack for 50 USD (5 users) and share the license with other people in your household.